# Can use one AWS bucket but not another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

This is my first time with AWS.

I successfully connected my `flask` app to AWS S3 bucket, using `boto3`.

**Problem description**

When I created the second one (copying settings from the first), this new bucket has a problem with `generate_presigned_url` method (got from official boto3 documentation), as this address sometimes gives following response:

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJNY34HRGQIPV7STA</AWSAccessKeyId>
  <StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20201016T175003Z 20201016/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request 1e048f40bac1a4332637056ef5fc2362a100943e3ab04391d3365dc7ab6d59d3</StringToSign> 
  <SignatureProvided>288c3569e008cc13ba3a3acb6a1210de0bf59e32707b46a9a173ed99c25bcdc8</SignatureProvided>
  <StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 30 31 30 31 36 54 31 37 35 30 30 33 5a 0a 32 30 32 30 31 30 31 36 2f 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 33 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 31 65 30 34 38 66 34 30 62 61 63 31 61 34 33 33 32 36 33 37 30 35 36 65 66 35 66 63 32 33 36 32 61 31 30 30 39 34 33 65 33 61 62 30 34 33 39 31 64 33 33 36 35 64 63 37 61 62 36 64 35 39 64 33</StringToSignBytes>
  <CanonicalRequest>GET /27.png X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJNY34HRGQIPV7STA%2F20201016%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201016T175003Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host host:ketocalcdev.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com host UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
  <CanonicalRequestBytes>47 45 54 0a 2f 32 37 2e 70 6e 67 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 4a 4e 59 33 34 48 52 47 51 49 50 56 37 53 54 41 25 32 46 32 30 32 30 31 30 31 36 25 32 46 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 33 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 32 30 31 30 31 36 54 31 37 35 30 30 33 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 33 36 30 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 6b 65 74 6f 63 61 6c 63 64 65 76 2e 73 33 2e 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 33 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes>
  <RequestId>6B3038A27F35B9D6</RequestId>
  <HostId>YjB+UrgpZo/gUS67gOqe4s9gvZ8uI2nQtfoZJadfIfVwaKgi/C0Ko0dHQ87VuYEFGu4jGsHJspU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Uploading files works fine
When using an old bucket (only changing the name in config), everything works perfectly everything.

**Already tried**

Tried to find any difference in bucket settings:

- region is the same
- permissions are the same, for bucket (see image) and for files:
  [image]

Tried to create new bucket.

**Code**
Slightly simplified code I use:

```py
def create_presigned_url(file, expiration=3600):
    from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
    import boto3
    from flask import current_app as app

    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id=app.config["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        aws_secret_access_key=app.config["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
        region_name="eu-west-3",
    )
    object_name = file.path
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            "get_object",
            Params={"Bucket": app.config["BUCKET"], "Key": object_name},
            ExpiresIn=expiration,
        )
    except ClientError:
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response
```

Only thing I change is BUCKET in config.
Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: add your flask code how you doing ?

Comment: This error happens when your provided AWS signature is not matching with AWS side signature when AWS received request.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I don't understand what that means for me. I am using my AWS account ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. I thought it works for all my buckets same way.

Comment: if you share your code it will helpful to understand your issue

Comment: @aviboy2006 added code. I'm using mostly code example from boto3 documentation. thank you for your time!

Comment: this error is getting while hitting presigned URL or getting presigned url ?

Comment: when hitting. I get url no problem, then I try to show it in `<img src={{file.url}}>` that gets the URL. template renders, image is replaced by placeholder, as it doesn't load. when clicking from devtools, get the XML page I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223179/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-janpeterka).

Comment: You might want to check the time on the server being used to generate the pre-signed URL, and compare it with the "true" time. If the time drifts too far, a request will not work. This might explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Can you please point me to how can I check the time on server? Thank you!

Comment: Also, I don't understand why there is problem with one bucket and not the other.

Answer (score 2):

**Generally why this error comes** ?

Signature matching mismatch means AWS do two side cross check signature values.

While calling `generate_presigned_url` its create one signature values in terms of `x-amz-security-token` this token is generated at Code end. When you send request and hit URL it will again calculated at AWS console side by same algo. If there is mismatch like file name, expiry time and bucket name etc request params its throw error "Signature Mismatch Error"

Check once your `expiry` variable and at what duration you are hitting URL.

Here is details : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

Comment: it stopped working again.
I don't really understand this answer, as there doesn't seem to be a problem with either filename, bucket name or expiry time (set to 3600s)